# How to visualize stickiness (DAU / MAU) in Apache superset

Tags: druid, apache-superset

i am new to Apache superset i want to implement chart it should represent stickiness means ratio of Daily active users/Monthly active users.
Using Druid as a datasource.
column present in my database "userId","event","timestamp".

Answer (score 0):

For DAU you just need to truncate `timestamp` to daily grain:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS dau, FLOOR(timestamp TO DAY) AS day
FROM your_datasource
GROUP BY FLOOR(timestamp TO DAY)
```

You can write the query above in SQL Lab, and then click "Visualize" to build a chart out of it. Alternatively, in the explore view you can choose "day" as the time grain, and then define the metric as `COUNT(DISTINCT userId)`.

For WAU/MAU, it's a bit more complicated. Traditionally you'd use a self join for the query, something like this (in pseudo-SQL):

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM your_datasource AS today
JOIN your_datasource AS last_month
ON last_month.timestamp BETWEEN today.timestamp AND (today.timestamp - 30 days)
```

But [Druid only supports equijoins](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html).